# XMLHttpRequest responding with undesired response

Tags: javascript, php, xmlhttprequest

I ran into trouble that i have failed to understand at all. I have a **sign up form**,**ajax script** and **php script**.My goal is that,i want to submit data to the php from the sign up form using ajax. My problem is that i can send but do not get the results that i desire as the response.
This is my sign-up form

```html
<form method="post" action="../../includes/seller.inc.php" id="form">
    <label for="names">First name and last name: </label><input type="text" name="names" id="names"> <br><br>
    <label for="phone">phone number: </label><input type="text" name="phone" id="phone"> <br><br>
    <label for="shopName">shop name: </label><input type="text" name="shopName" id="shopName"> <br><br>
    <label for="email">Email: </label><input type="text" name="email" id="email"> <br><br>
    <label for="pwd">Password: </label><input type="password" name="pwd" id="pwd"> <br><br>
    <label for="pwd2">Retype Password: </label><input type="password" name="pwd2" id="pwd2"> <br><br>
    <label for="description">Provide a brief Description</label><textarea name="description" id="description" cols="30" rows="5"></textarea> <br><br>
    <button type="submit" name="submit">submit</button><br>
</form>
```

And this is my PHP script(action specified by the form):

```php
$names = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["names"]);
$phone = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["phone"]);
$shopName = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["shopName"]);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["email"]);
$pwd = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["pwd"]);
$pwd2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["pwd2"]);
$description = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["description"]);

//validating the user input data
if(!empty($names && $phone && $shopName && $email && $pwd && $pwd2)){
    if (preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/",$names)) {
        if (preg_match("/^[0-9+](\d)+$/",$phone)) {
            if(preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/",$shopName)) {
                if(filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                    if ($pwd !== $pwd2) {
                        header("Location: ../sell/auth/sell.signup.php?passwordsdoNotMatch");
                    } else {
                        $hashed_pwd = password_hash($pwd, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
                        $sql = "INSERT INTO seller(name,phone,shopName,email,password,description,approval_status) VALUES ('$names','$phone','$shopName','$email','$hashed_pwd','$description','0');";

                        if(!mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
                            echo "sorry not added".mysqli_error($conn);
                        } else {
                            header("Location: ../index.php");
                            $_SESSION['actionmsg-success'] = "successfully Added .Wait for approval!! so that you may post your products.";
                        }
                    }
```

And this is the ajax

```js
function loadFunc() {
    const names = document.getElementById('names');
    const phone = document.getElementById('phone');
    const shopName = document.getElementById('shopName');
    const email = document.getElementById('email');
    const pwd = document.getElementById('pwd');
    const pwd2 = document.getElementById('pwd2');
    const description = document.getElementById('description');

    var form = document.getElementById('form');
    form.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var params = `names=${names}&phone=${phone},shopName=${shopName},email=${email}&pwd=${pwd}&pwd2=${pwd2}&description=${description}`;
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('post', '../../includes/seller.inc.php');
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        xhr.onload = function () {
            if (this.readyState == 4) {
                console.log(this.responseText);
            }
        }
        xhr.send(params);
    });
}
```

When running them i dont get an error but i get a response of my own html code printed to the browser.[image]

Comment: Your PHP code has to perform two actions. It has to handle the incoming AJAX request (validation, run SQL statements etc.) and it also has to provide the right type of response that the AJAX handler can deal with. This is normally plain text or JSON. Currently, you are issuing header redirects which is bad news for the AJAX handler. Simply `echo` out some message strings and go from there.

Comment: i used header directs incase a problem occurs but if everything went on fine , I echoed out the information i needed to fetch from the script